# Find name of member in list

Tags: c#

I want find name of member in generic list, can we help me to solve this problem?
I must check each user in list and if one of value equals with eg "100" must know name of this value.
I know how to work with parameter values but I can't get properties.

Regards

```
public List<Users> LiUsers = new List<Users>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int r = 100;
        foreach (var user in LiUsers)
        {

             //do some stuff

            //here I want name of member which equals int r ... eg  "Value1" or "Value2" ...

        }
    }

    private void FillUsers(string name, int id, int val1, int val2, int val3, int val4, int val5)
    {
        LiUsers.Add(new Users { Name = name, Id = id, Value1 = val1, Value2 = val2, Value3 = val3, Value4 = val4, Value5 = val4 });
    }
}
public class Users : IEnumerable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
    public int Value4 { get; set; }
    public int Value5 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return Name;
        yield return Id;
        yield return Value1;
        yield return Value2;
        yield return Value3;
        yield return Value4;
        yield return Value5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check the property values by reflection?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Your design is really weird. Why do you need to do this? What are these `Values` actually going to represent in your code?

Comment: If Selman's answer is closer to what you required - change your object. Use a `Dictionary` or some other hash to  perform lookups like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the values of your properties using Reflection and then use LINQ to get name of the property that has the value of 100:

```
var userType = typeof(User);
var properties = userType
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Value")).ToList();

foreach (var user in LiUsers)
{
    var property  = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x.GetValue(user) == 100);
    if(property != null)
    {
        string name = property.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use .First() instead of .Any since he wants the member name.

Comment: Why would you need reflection?

Comment: I am so very confused as to the OP's requirements now. We need clarification.

Comment: @BenAaronson, because he wants the member name (if there is one) that has the desired value.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET So, use a big `if...else if...else` statement? It's generally not a good thing to do, but I don't think reflection should be used just to make code neater. I removed the downvote though

Comment: @BenAaronson, I personally would rather use reflection than have a 50 block if/else if set, but that's just me. Seems like a situation that reflection was designed for.

Comment: I would turn all 50+ properties into a `Dictionary` instead. The lookup would be faster than constantly iterating over it via reflection.

Comment: Seems like a situation that dictionaries were designed for.

Comment: I agree dictionary is a better idea, but without changing the design I believe using Reflection is the right option.And it is possible that OP can't change this code, maybe he is using third party library or some code that has been written by somebody else.. who knows.